# I get a syntax error when trying to translate into broken english using Googletrans API (Python 3.8.1)?

Tags: python, syntax, google-translation-api, googletrans

This is very much a dumb thing to ask, however I'm new to Python. I just installed googletrans from PyPI and I wanted to make a program that runs a phrase through a set of translations to make the phrase come out as broken English. However, I get a Syntax error! I can't figure it out and I've Googled everywhere. Please help!

```
from googletrans import Translator
import os

translator = Translator()

def addToClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)

one = (translator.translate(input("ENTER PHRASE"))
two = (translator.translate(one, dest='sp'))
three = (translator.translate(two, dest='ch'))
four = (translator.translate(three, dest='fi'))
five = (translator.translate(four, dest='ja'))

result = (translator.translate(five))

addToClipBoard(result.text)

print("Copied succesfully. Closing now...")

exit()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a bracket at the end here:

```
one = (translator.translate(input("ENTER PHRASE")) # <- missing bracket
# should be
one = (translator.translate(input("ENTER PHRASE"))) # <- see the extra bracket
```

I recommend using a linter, like [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/). Linters catch syntax/style errors for you. If you use a text editor like vscode or pycharm, it's really easy to have it work in the background while you code so you can fix your syntax errors while coding.

Comment: Thank you! That was just a total oversight on my end...